# simulate double click or press like button on instagram

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I am so bad in JavaScript I want try to create a command for chrome console that click like button or double click all image (post) in Instagram home, I try use function:

```
document.getElementById(id).click()
```

or by class name
but nothing. I don't know how to use because like button isn't a button for use this:

```
$('#button1').click()
```

what function I should use for let a work script for autolike on Instagram?
I've just tried all this function but I'm bad in JavaScript, if I try this code it can't find button like... I should find it with id or class name?

Comment: you can use jQuery

`jQuery( "#button1" ).dblclick();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Double click:

```
$( "#target" ).dblclick();
```

For more information and usage, you can refer : https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: <a class="_tk4ba _1tv0k" href="#" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="_soakw coreSpriteHeartOpen">Mi piace</span></a>         this is the elements html of like btton...what i must insert in #target?